# how i can solve "ERROR: Could not find net.simonvt.schematic:-compiler:0.6.3."

Tags: android, android-studio

ERROR: Could not find net.simonvt.schematic:-compiler:0.6.3.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/net/simonvt/schematic/-compiler/0.6.3/-compiler-0.6.3.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/net/simonvt/schematic/-compiler/0.6.3/-compiler-0.6.3.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/simonvt/schematic/-compiler/0.6.3/-compiler-0.6.3.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/simonvt/schematic/-compiler/0.6.3/-compiler-0.6.3.jar
Required by:
    project :app

i tried to change version and change project place to make the path length less

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.example.com.squawker"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation'junit:junit:4.12'

```
// RecyclerView
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

// Schematic dependencies for ContentProvider
apt 'net.simonvt.schematic:-compiler:0.6.3'
implementation 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic:0.6.3'

// Preferences Dependencies
implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'
```

}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.example.com.squawker"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation'junit:junit:4.12'

```
// RecyclerView
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

// Schematic dependencies for ContentProvider
apt 'net.simonvt.schematic:-compiler:0.6.3'
implementation 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic:0.6.3'

// Preferences Dependencies
implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'
```

}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkDmi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have the dependency path wrong. Can you try changing your dependency block to:

```
annotationProcessor 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic-compiler:0.6.3'
compile 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic:0.6.3'
```

Note that it should be `schematic-compiler`, not `-compiler`.

Answer (score 1):

Project level "build.gradle" remove this line:

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.2'
```

App level "build.gradle" remove this line:

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
```

and change this line replacing apt with annotationProcessor:

```
apt 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic-compiler:0.6.3'
```